# Spring 3.1 @Scheduled firing randomly

Tags: java, spring, cron

I am trying to execute a method using the annotation @Scheduled and a cron value.
The method executes but does not respect the cron.

Here is my class :

```
@Component
public class Test {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.debug("run()");
    }
}
```

Part of my applicationContext.xml :

```
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<bean id="run" class="xxx.Test"></bean>
```

I am using Spring 3.1 with spring-task-3.1.xsd in my xml.

And when I start, I should have a line every 10 seconds, and I get this :

```
12/16 15:51:20,033 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:51:29,996 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:54:09,657 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:54:10,000 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
12/16 15:54:19,978 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:54:34,664 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:22,137 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:34,656 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
12/16 15:55:39,988 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:49,981 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:59:07,278 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
```

The delay between each execution changes every time. I tested with FixedRate or FixedDelay but I get the same result.

So the class is correctly found, the method too, but it fires randomly.

Does anybody have an idea of what can cause this kind of behaviour?

I have been searching for hours now without any success. Putting the scheduled part in the xml instead of the java file does not change anything, trying with a properties file for the cron value either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cron` expression in

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
```

is saying "execute this method on every second that is divisible by 10", in other words, 10, 20, 30, etc. That's what it seems like it's doing (+/- the precision of the scheduler)

```
12/16 15:54:09,657 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:54:10,000 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
12/16 15:54:19,978 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
```

but it some times skips or has long intervals

```
12/16 15:54:19,978 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:54:34,664 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:22,137 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:34,656 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
12/16 15:55:39,988 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:55:49,981 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run() 
12/16 15:59:07,278 [---] [DEBUG] [Test:31] - run()
```

This can happen if the threads in the `TaskScheduler` are busy with something else or are blocked for some reason. You will need to give more details about your setup if you want more information.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the idea of the task scheduler being busy. I tried to run my program on another computer (my personal one, the first one was at work) and it's working perfectly. I suppose that all the security programs installed at work prevent my program to run correctly. After two days of research about this problem, it's solved ! Thanks.